# FreeBSD 9.2: how do I install libcurl with openssl?

Tags: libcurl, freebsd

On Ubuntu I use this command:

```
apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

On FreeBSD, I've tried this, which doesn't work:

```
pkg_add -r libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

I've tried looking through the list of ports here, and didn't see anything obvious:

```
http://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/ports/amd64/packages-9.2-release/Latest
```

What's the equivalent install package for FreeBSD (9.2 specifically)?

Comment: I found that to simply install curl the command is: pkg_add -r curl  According to the curl web site http://curl.haxx.se, they say that SSL is enabled by default, so maybe that's all I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The library `libcurl` is installed by the port `ftp/curl`:

```
pkg which -o /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.7 
/usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.7 was installed by package ftp/curl
```

(N.B: I'm using FreeBSD 10.0 which uses a newer package management program. On 9.2 you can use `pkg_which` instead)

As you can see on the [curl freshports page](http://www.freshports.org/ftp/curl/), OpenSSL is enabled by default.

So installing a package would be enough unless you want to use another SSL implementation or if you want to change any of the other options. In that case you'll have to install it from ports by running the following commands as the `root` user;

```
# cd /usr/ports/ftp/curl
# make config
# make install clean
```

If you have never installed this port before, you can skip the `make config` step because it will be done anyway.